# Create a new download page on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, download

I am trying to create a separate download page in WordPress when the visitor clicks on a download link, it will be redirected to a download page with a counter like this site below. I will donate if someone help me solve the problem.

https://wpshare.net/tmusers-1-0-bbpress-forum-member-directory-for-elementor/

Answer (score 0):

Look for a useful wordpress plugin and do it yourself or hire someone on a freelance site to help you out with this one time request.

To solve your problem:

1. Create a new page called "download-thing" make it look however you want. OR copy an existing page and edit the content if you really don't know what you're doing.
2. Look for a wordpress plugin that will allow you to manage the download of files like [this one](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/download-manager/).
3. Install the plugin in wordpress follow [this guide](https://wordpress.org/support/article/managing-plugins/).
4. Go back to the new page you created and use the plugin to download the file automatically.
5. Use an ordinary button to link users to the new page from wherever you want.